# How to get URI from file with FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

How can I get `URI` from a file with a dynamic folder in the path?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /storage/emulated/0/AppName/155522864927/media/1555228649276.mp4

It works fine only if I set hardcoded path

`<external-path name="/" path="AppName/155522864927/media/" />`

Comment: `"dynamic folder"`? what is it?

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: I have created a folder with a random name

Comment: I am creating own folder for every user. But can't get uri from these folders(

Comment: try `path="AppName/media/"` for example and create folders like `/storage/emulated/0/AppName/media/155522864927` and call `getUriForFile` with a `File` like  `/storage/emulated/0/AppName/media/155522864927/sound.mp4`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path cannot be random. You need to configure the path that you expose. For more info please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles).